# Node.js app works locally, doesn't on Firebase

Tags: javascript, node.js, email, firebase, nodemailer

I have a very simple, one page node.js app that uses nodemailer to email any form data to my inbox, using my email.

My index.js file:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'gmail',
    auth: {
        user: 'myemail@gmail.com',
        pass: 'mypassword'
    }
});

app.use(express.static('public')); //Folder with static pages
app.get('', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/");
})

app.post('/', function (req, res) {
    response = {
        name: req.body.name,
        email: req.body.email,
        message: req.body.message
    };
    var mailClient = {
        from: 'myemail@gmail.com',
        to: 'myemail@gmail.com',
        subject: `Message from ${response.name}`,
        text: `Name: ${response.name}\nEmail: ${response.email}\nMessage:${response.message}`
    };


    transporter.sendMail(mailClient, function (error, info) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        } else {
            res.redirect("/success.html");
        }
    });
})

var server = app.listen(80, function () {
    var host = server.address().address
    var port = server.address().port
    console.log("App listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)
})
```

The app works perfectly fine locally, on `npm start`. However, when I deploy to Firebase, it seems the nodemailer part doesn't work. The page loads in with my static files, but when I try to submit anything via the form, the page simply refreshes (like when you have a submit button with bare html), instead of redirecting me to my success page and emailing data.

I have minimized my app to just the simple form that retains the previously stated problems when deployed to Firebase, and uploaded it to github here:  https://github.com/KadinZ/FirebaseProblem. I took the liberty of creating a testing gmail account that is used in the uploaded app, with email, nodemailersampleemail@gmail.com, and password, foopassword. So the app should work if anyone wants to download the repo and test it.

I also uploaded this minimized app to firebase here: https://portfolio-fe3eb.firebaseapp.com/, to display the problem thats happening.

Extra info: I'm on the blaze plan for Firebase, and I'm getting no error logs.

What's going on?

Comment: Perhaps this is useful, you need to set this up a little differently when deploying to Firebase: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47896690/how-to-deploy-express-to-firebase

Comment: @ScottKronheim I am also facing the same issue. I have followed your link, and also the docs. Does it take some time to completely deploy the projects on firebase ? Because my application is working absolutely fine on local. But after deploy I am not able to send the request to another server through my live application. What could be the reasons it went wrong ?