# How to deploy express to Firebase?

Tags: firebase, express, google-cloud-functions

Currently i'm learning express and Firebase. I can deploy an angular or react page (front-end) to Firebase.

And now, i'm trying to create the back-end using express, then i realize, i cant just simply deploying it as another project to Firebase since Firebase hosting will looking for index.html as entry point (*please correct me if i'm wrong). I've tried Firebase functions but still can't.

Can i set a javascript (expressjs) file to Firebase as entry point?

thanks.

Answer (score 9):

You can deploy an Express app to [Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/) as an [HTTP trigger](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events).  There is a [sample](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/authenticated-json-api) that illustrates this.  The basic form of implementation looks like this in your Cloud Functions index.js:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions')
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
// configure app here, add routes, whatever
exports.api = functions.https.onRequest(app)
```

Now you can access your routes under the path https://your-assigned-hostname/api/whatever

**EDIT**

You also need to configure your *firebase.json* file if you want to redirect every request to the Express app.

Add this line inside the *hosting* object: `"rewrites" : [{"source" : "**", "function" : "api"}]`

Comment: Hi Doug, I have followed your link, and also the docs. Does it take some time to completely deploy the projects on firebase ? Because my application is working absolutely fine on local. But after deploy I am not able to send the request to another server through my live application. What could be the reasons it went wrong ?